# Ninject 3 InRequestScope not returning the same instance for the same request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-extensions

Recently, I upgraded one of my MVC3 projects from Ninject 2 to Ninject 3.

After a couple of minutes trying to find why InRequestScope was not anymore available, I found that this is now an extension of Ninject.Web.Common.

Now, when I try to run the application, Ninject works like if all types binded with a scope InRequest would be InTransientScope; a new instance was created each time.

In my class that inherits from NinjectModule, I have a simple bind like that:

```
Bind<ViewModel.Activity>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

In my controller, I have 2 properties of the type ViewModel.Activity marked with Ninject attribute.

```
  [Inject]
  public ViewModel.Activity Activity { get; set; }

  [Inject]
  public ViewModel.Activity Activity1 { get; set; }
```

If I looked in debug mode the value of the HashCode of both the two properties, there all have different value but HttpContext is the same; I'm in the same request.

What I missed about how to use correctly the new Ninject.Web.Common.InRequestScope with the new version of Ninject 3?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How are you hooking Ninject into your code?  Are you using Ninject.MVC3 from nuget, and then editing the NinjectWebCommon.cs file?  or are you doing a custom controller factory?

Comment: @MystereMan Thank you very much. This is exactly what I want. I used NuGet to find Ninject MVC3 and just add what you said in NinjectWebCommon for the bind of my dependencies and it works. I think the key why this work is because of these lines:          DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof (OnePerRequestHttpModule)); and DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof (NinjectHttpModule)); OnePerRequestHttpModule will also dispose all my unit of work immeditaly after each request. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Added as an answer so this can be closed out**

Don't use a custom factory. Just install Ninject.MVC3 and copy your bindings over to the NinjectWebCommon.cs file, then delete all your old code.

Comment: What is this comment added at the beginning of the answer?

Comment: @Samuel - I had originally posted this as a comment, but you asked me to post it as an answer so it could be marked as the answer.  So I did, and you did in fact mark it as the answer.  Then, for some reason, you suddenly decided to unmark it as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Ninject.Web.Common can't be used standalone. You must use some additional web or wcf extension or implement InRequestScope yourself.

Comment: Thank you Remo for your time. Do you have a sample of code of how to implement it. In my module, I use the bind syntax for the type I wish to be injected and with the help of a using ninject.web.common, I call at the end of the bind instruction the method InRequestScope. It not enough to tell ninject which scope I want?

Comment: No that's not enough, because InRequestScope can mean InWCFRequestScope or InHttpRequestScope and in future propably other scopes as well. Web.Common does not know anything about the various request types. I strongly advice to use one of the Web extensions. There is no reason for implementing own factories and I don't give any support on them. Look at the extensions and copy all the logic from there if you really want to use your own factory.

Comment: Hi Remo, thank you helping me. I searched into the extensions and google 'InHttpRequestScope' but I don't found any information helping me to implement InHttpRequestScope. In which extension could I find this method, class?

Comment: @Samuel Did you look in Ninject.Extension.Mvc* and Ninject.Extensions.Wcf ?

Comment: Thank you guys. Like I said to MystereMan in a comment, including reference to Ninject MVC3 with NuGet, this solved all my problems.