# Ninject's in InRequestScope doesn't seem to return the same instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

We made the mistake to define a new DbContext in each of our repositories. So during development, we were walking into a lot of these kind of errors:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

So instead of disposing everywhere we figured the best thing to do is to make sure all of our repositories use the same context in each request. We had a NinjectControllerFactory initially, where we also placed our repository bindings. I installed the Ninject.Web.Commons nuget package and it created the NinjectWebCommon.cs file in App_Start.

I moved my bindings all over to the NinjectWebCommon file, and made the NinjectControllerFactory use the same kernel. I added our DbContext class as a binding and gave it the InRequestScope method.

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<EfDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Each repository is now using referring to the context through the constructor.

```
public class EfPageRepository : IPageRepository
{
    EfDbContext context;

    public EfPageRepository(EfDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.context = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Now the project builds fine, but we are still getting the same error as I described in the beginning of this post. Did I forgot a step here? I really can't find why it is not working.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591203/ninject-3-inrequestscope-not-returning-the-same-instance-for-the-same-request?rq=1

Comment: We had a custom factory, but it was setup to use the webcommons file's IKernel, so that was not the problem. However, installing Ninject.MVC3 seemed to have solved our problem. Thank you.