# How to share the same instance in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I am trying to use Ninject for IoC with ASP.NET MVC 5.

My controller has a constructor like this:

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unit;
private readonly IContactService contactService;

public ContactsController(IUnitOfWork unit, IContactService contactService)
{
    this._unit = unit;
    this._contactService = contactService;
}
```

So the `ContactService` has a constructor (IUnitOfWork unit) and should share the same instance of the IUnitOfWork, but Ninject is giving a new different instance. My ContactService derives of a class with this constructor:

```
public ServiceBase(IUnitOfWork unit)
{
    _unit = unit;
    _repository = _unit.GetRepository<TEntity>();
}
```

My ninject config bindings:

```
public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{

    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IContactService>().To<ContactService>().InRequestScope();;

}
```

I hope that `InRequestScope()` give the same instance per request, but that is not happening.

Comment: And how do you know that it's not the same instance?  And can you show the constructor of ContactService?

Comment: If `InRequestScope()` is not working it's usually due to a misconfiguration of Ninject / not using the right packages. There's quite a few posts on stackoverflow regarding that matter. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591203/ninject-3-inrequestscope-not-returning-the-same-instance-for-the-same-request and I think there was/is an issue where the order in which you install the packages can break it,... not sure if this is still the case, though.

Comment: You should be right @BatteryBackupUnit. In fact I am reusing a config from another project, wich does'nt uses ninject.web. I will check that. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I now because I my code doesnt works appropriately, so I checked it.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem now. I had `Ninject` and `Ninject.Web.Common` packages installed and I was injecting dependencies using my custom `NinjectControllerFactory`. Using *Erik's* response linked by *BatteryBackupUnit's* in comments, I have decided to uninstall my Ninject packages and I have installed **Ninject.MVC5** package.

The package generated a `NinjectWebCommon.cs` Ninject confgiuration file in the `App_Start` folder. The only thing you need to do is to copy your bindings to `RegisterServices` method in `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file and stop using your custom NinjectControllerFactory (if you have one).

It solved my problem, hope it solves your problem as well.